# How to redefine a product command to add an optional argument?

Tags: macros, spacing, math-operators, optional-arguments, arguments

I would like to redefine the product commands (`\times`, `\cdot`, `\otimes`, `\wedge`, `\odot`) to add an **optional negative spacing argument**, but I don't know how to do this in a proper way.  I need the new `\times` command to stays the same as the old `\times` when no argument is added to it, and `\times[?]` (or `\times{?}` ??) be the command with a **negative space added to the left side**.  How to do that in a proper way?

More specifically, I need the new command to work in the following way:

`a \times b` gives the same output as the old `a \times b`.

`a \time[1] b` gives the same output as `a \mskip-1mu \times b`

`a \time[2] b` gives the same output as `a \mskip-2mu \times b`

Here's a MWE code to play with:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

TEST
\begin{align}
    a &\times b \\
    a \mskip-1mu &\times b \\
    a \mskip-2mu &\times b
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why not simply `\def\z#1{\muskip-#1mu}` then `a \z1\times b`  does what you want with only three characters, the same as the suggested `[1]` without redefining standard commands and making your math fragments incompatible with every other latex math setup

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, just for uniformization of my preamble, what would be your command syntax using the \newcommand* style?

Comment: `\newcommand\z[1]{\muskip-#1mu}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks a lot.  I think I'll use your command...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to redefine a lot of standard commands which would make your math expressions very fragile and likely to clash with other packages and confuse co-authors.

I would simply define something like

```
\newcommand\z[1]{\mskip-#1mu}
```

then use

```
a \z1\times b
```

when you want to adjust the spacing. (You might want to give a more meaningful name than `\z` or perhaps not, and keep it short)

Comment: Would simply \1 be allowed?

Comment: No, I mean something like \1, \2, ...

Comment: @Cham well I showed you how to define `\1` you can define `\2` the same way. You could  define `\3` as well. (although that is usually the same as `\!` I doubt you would need anything bigger for small adjustments

Comment: Ok thanks.  I'll experiment with all this...

Comment: Your macro doesn't work.  I'm getting an error message: Bad register code (-1).  Missing number, treated as zero.

Comment: @Cham sorry typo (I'll fix) should be `\mskip` (as in your question) not `\muskip`

Comment: `\newcommand\1{\mskip-1mu} `

Answer (score 0):

You can abstract the redefinitions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\addspacer}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \cham_addspacer:N
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \cham_addspacer:N
 {
  \exp_args:Nc \NewCommandCopy { \cs_to_str:N #1 _kept } #1
  \RenewDocumentCommand #1 { O{0} }
   {
    \mskip-##1mu
    \use:c { \cs_to_str:N #1 _kept }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\addspacer{\times,\cdot,\otimes,\wedge}

\begin{document}

$a\times b$

$a\times[1]b$

$a\times[2]b$

$a\wedge b$

$a\wedge[1]b$

$a\wedge[2]b$

\end{document}
```

[image]